Turning a grid map array into a shapely object
I have a (2000x2000) python array of 0's and 1's that represent whether a cell is free or not. I'd like to turn this dense representation into a shapely object.
For example, an array of the type:
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0

would become a square.
I tried building one cell at a time and joining it to the larger shape or building an array of individual squares and joining them together but it's proving to be too slow. How can i obtain the shape in a more efficient way?

I think whenever you try manipulate Shapely library multiple times any such manipulation would add a significant processing delay. I think the most efficient way is to process the whole array, creating a set of point coordinates in memory (not Point objects in Shapely), and then create a single Shapely object, some kind of Multipoint, built from all the available points in the array in one single operation. I have no idea if it's mathematically possible, but it should be, using the same algorithms you are using now but not using Shapely for that.

Can you post an example code which does what you want to accomplish on a smaller set? Then from there we can see the expected input and output and try to answer the performance problem on the 2000x2000 set.

You can use rasterio.features.shapes for this.
This is an (untested) code snippet that shows how you can create a geopandas dataframe by polygonizing the information in a numpy array:
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio.features as rio_features
import shapely.geometry as sh_geom

polygonized_records = list(rio_features.shapes(numpy_array))

# Convert shapes to geopandas geodataframe
data = [
    (sh_geom.shape(geom), int(value)) for geom, value in polygonized_records
]
result_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, columns=["geometry", "value"])

